# how can we traverse/point to particular string on html page using python

Tags: python, html

My requirement is we have two html pages. One contains the hyperlinks and other html contains the detailed responses related to hyperlinks. When I click hyperlink on first html, it should point to the respective string/block responses on second html using python.
I was able to convert text file to html files but not able to point to string on HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say your first HTML page looks like this:

```html
...
<a href="data.html">Your website title</a>
...
```

And your second HTML page has some similar looking information enclosed in `<p>` tags.

```html
...
<p>This is some information about your website title</p>
...
```

I'm making the assumption here that your second file is called `data.html`, but it's obviously whatever you named it. Before every `<p>` tag, you can add:

```html
<a name="title"></a>
```

where you `title` is a unique name for every paragraph that you want to tag.

Then, in your original HTML file, you'll want to change all the URLs so instead of `data.html` you'll have `data.html#title` where `title` is the name of the corresponding paragraph from the other file.

So as an example, it would look something like this:

file.html:

```html
...
<a href="data.html#cats">Link to the first paragraph</a>
<a href="data.html#dogs">Link to the second paragraph</a>
...
```

data.html:

```html
...
<a name="cats"></a><p>This is a paragraph about cats</p>
<a name="dogs"></a><p>This is a paragraph about dogs</p>
...
```

**Edit**

So I reread your question and realized you wanted to do this in Python. However, you said that you wanted to be able to click the hyperlinks. Are you trying to make this user-clickable on a website (HTML), or traverse the HTML programatically?